# What is the purpose of manifest.json in a Cassandra snaphot?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, nodetool

When a snapshot is made a manifest.json is created, what is the purpose of this file? I would have thought it contained a list of all files in the snapshot, which are:

```
2014-11-11 17:36:51         43 keyspace-cf-ka-1-CompressionInfo.db
2014-11-11 17:36:51         87 keyspace-cf-ka-1-Data.db
2014-11-11 17:36:51         10 keyspace-cf-ka-1-Digest.sha1
2014-11-11 17:36:51         16 keyspace-cf-ka-1-Filter.db
2014-11-11 17:36:51         25 keyspace-cf-ka-1-Index.db
2014-11-11 17:36:51       4460 keyspace-cf-ka-1-Statistics.db
2014-11-11 17:36:51        101 keyspace-cf-ka-1-Summary.db
2014-11-11 17:36:51         91 keyspace-cf-ka-1-TOC.txt
2014-11-11 17:36:51         43 keyspace-cf.field2_field1_idx-ka-1-CompressionInfo.db
2014-11-11 17:36:51         63 keyspace-cf.field2_field1_idx-ka-1-Data.db
2014-11-11 17:36:51          9 keyspace-cf.field2_field1_idx-ka-1-Digest.sha1
2014-11-11 17:36:51         16 keyspace-cf.field2_field1_idx-ka-1-Filter.db
2014-11-11 17:36:51         25 keyspace-cf.field2_field1_idx-ka-1-Index.db
2014-11-11 17:36:51       4458 keyspace-cf.field2_field1_idx-ka-1-Statistics.db
2014-11-11 17:36:51        101 keyspace-cf.field2_field1_idx-ka-1-Summary.db
2014-11-11 17:36:51         91 keyspace-cf.field2_field1_idx-ka-1-TOC.txt
2014-11-11 17:36:51         62 manifest.json
```

but instead it contains:

```
{
    "files": [
        "keyspace-cf.field2_field1_idx-ka-1-Data.db"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I contains all the **sstables** included in the snapshot.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6326

Comment: I am not sure that is correct another manifest.json for a table with an index contains an entry only for an index .db file. I have updated the question to reflect this.